# How can i restart elements when loading a new layout?

Tags: android

So I'm building this "Where's Waldo" type of game and I try loading a different layout each time our "Waldo" has been found. Here's my code:

```
public class MainGame extends AppCompatActivity {


public int time = 101;
public int score = 0;
TextView scoreText,timeText;
Thread t;
public Button press;
Random r = new Random();
public int x = r.nextInt(3) + 1;
int counter=0;
private static int MESSAGE_CHANGEVIEW = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level1);
    timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    press = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    t=new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            timeText.setText(String.valueOf(time));
                            scoreText.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                        }
                    });
                    if (time != 0) {
                        time--;
                        //System.out.println(time);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
            }
        }
    };




    t.start();

    press.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    time = 101;
                    counter += 1;
                    score += time;
                    System.out.println(counter);
                    System.out.println(x);
                    System.out.println(score);


                            switch (x) {
                                case 1:
                                    setContentView(R.layout.level1);
                                    recreate();
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    setContentView(R.layout.level2);
                                    recreate();
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    setContentView(R.layout.level3);
                                    recreate();
                                    break;
                            }
                }
            });
        }
    });


    }
```

In my code, time is a timer that decreases each second, score is the current score, and the counter should make sure I only played 3 levels. The x in the switch statement is a value that is randomized each time I press the button. My problem is that whenever I load one of the three layouts, all my functionality disappears (the buttons doesn't work, my counter and my score don't appear). Anyone have an idea of how to solve this? And no, I'm not making a different activity for each level so that I can repeat the code n times. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Handler and do setContentView() in handleMessage() of Handler.

```
private static int MESSAGE_CHANGEVIEW = 1;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, ">>>handleMessage");
        // set your view depending upon value of x
        return true;
    }
});
```

In your onClick() method Call

```
mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_CHANGEVIEW);
```

Comment: what do you mean by that? could you detail with some code please?

Comment: i added the sample to use handler

Comment: so you mean that my switch statement should be inside the handleMessage() method?

Comment: Yes you can do it if your variable x is global variable.

Comment: well i did it and it's still not working for me. let me update my question with the whole code. Can you edit on it and see what you can get?

Answer (score 0):

you can setContentView with a rootView (eg only LinearLayout),and then use this rootView addView level1 and leve2 leve3

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have 3 different fragments.

```
fragmentA, fragmentB, fragment3.
```

And do use handler:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //then inside your switch cases do

           /* getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragmentA, TAG); */

            /* getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragmentB, TAG); */

            /* getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragmentC, TAG); */
        }
    }, SOME_DELAY);
}
```